# HTMX not working when loaded within template tag using Alpine js (x-if)

Tags: django, alpine.js, htmx

For a Django project I am trying to build a toggle component to switch from list to grid view without reloading the page. I am using a Flowbite toggle component. Using Alpine's `x-if` I am able to dynamically change the HTML for the list view and the grid view which are contained in two template tags within the same alpine component. Here is a simplified version of the component:

```html
<div x-data="{ value: false }">

  <!-- Toggle component from Flowbite -->
  <label class="relative inline-flex items-center cursor-pointer">
    <input x-model="value" type="checkbox" value="" class="sr-only peer">
    <div class="w-11 h-6 bg-slate-300 peer-focus:outline-none peer-focus:ring-4 peer-focus:ring-yellow-300 rounded-full peer peer-checked:after:translate-x-full peer-checked:after:border-white after:content-[''] after:absolute after:top-[2px] after:left-[2px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-5 after:w-5 after:transition-all peer-checked:bg-yellow-500"></div>
    <span class="ml-2 font-medium text-slate-600 mdi mdi-view-grid"></span>
  </label>

  <!-- Template tags with the HTML code -->
  <template x-if="value===true">
    <div>
      <a href="{% url 'inventory:inventory' %}">HREF</a>
    </div>
  </template>

  <template x-if="value===false">
    <div>
      <a hx-get="{% url 'inventory:inventory %}">HX-GET</a>
    </div>
  </template>

</div>
```

The toggle works just fine. However, while the toggled code with the href url works just fine, the code with the hx-get attribute (HTMX) does not work. Clicking on the link does not do anything.
I suppose this has to do with inserting HTMX properties after the page is already loaded, thus HTMX does not 'see' the code toggled via alpine js.

I tried to apply hx-on (with htmx:load to the main div but I could not make it work. What can be done to make the hx-get attribute work after being added to the page via alpine?

Comment: is there anything in browser console when you try clicking that hx-get anchor tag? can you try giving your anchor tag with hx-get  an id or name so that htmx can target that tag when it receives the results from the server request

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTMX [mentions this phenomena in the documentation](https://htmx.org/docs/#3rd-party), you have to call [`htmx.process()`](https://htmx.org/api/#process) on the DOM elements that were not present/visible on page load. You can call this method from e.g. a [`$watch`](https://alpinejs.dev/magics/watch):

```
<div id="mycomponent" 
     x-data="{ value: false }" 
     x-init="$watch('value', new_value => {htmx.process(htmx.find('#mycomponent'))})">
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. `hx-get` attribute fires correctly when the a tag is clicked. The loaded content is added just within the anchor tag. 
However, in my real case I want to set a different target div too. Adding `hx-target="#myDiv"` did not work. The documentation does not seem to say anything about this. Their example only uses hx-get.

Comment: Nevermind my last comment. The `hx-target` also works correctly. The problem is that I am also using Flowbite's modal window as the target...and for some reason the content is added to the modal but the modal remains hidden. Therefore. the problem should now be with the Flowbite's `data-modal-target` and `data-modal-toggle` attributes which when loaded via alpine, do not fire..
Is there a similar solution as we just did for HTMX?

Comment: Yes, you need to trigger the modal open with e.g. `hx-on="htmx:afterSettle: htmx.find('#mymodal').open()"`.